# how to fault find if a delegate call is not being picked up in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

Just implementing my first delegate in objective-C.  I thought I had everything in place however the call from my AddController back to ListController isn't being picked up in the ListController.

Given that I'm not getting an exception, and that I can see that the code does get to the point in the AddController where it calls the delegate, are there any fault finding tips?

So for example:

- given the "delegate" call (see below) did not throw an exception can I assume that my delegate declarations in the same file are OK?

  "[delegate newItemController:self didFinishWithSave:YES];"
- given the parent controller so to speak does have the delegate specified in the *.h definition (see below), then this does implied I've correctly implemented the method in the *.m file, noting I get no build errors?

  @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController  {
- is there a known way for delegate calls to go missing without an exception if certain items don't like up (i.e. if there is what should I check for)

thanks

Comment: make sure you have assigned your `delegate` member variable to a valid Objective-C class.

Comment: Have you checked that your delegate is set and not nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most common error I've seen for a delegate method not being called is a nil delegate property.  In other words, forgetting to specify who the delegate is?

As for debugging tips, anytime I've seen a problem where a delegate is not being called is to set breakpoints throughout the code and step through the code.  Then you can see where things are going and what is or isn't being called.

Also, you mention exceptions a lot.  Objective C prefers not to use exceptions as they are a relatively expensive call in the language (unlike say Java). Objective C can and does use exceptions but they are rare. You might want to "beaf up" your understanding of error handling in objective c.

Comment: thanks - used code stepping and I see when I call the delegate it doesn't seem assigned

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your delegate variable like this in your AddController:

```
self.delegate = <instance of ListViewController>
```

If it has not been set, then the delegate would be nil and the method call to the nil would result in nothing. Otherwise, delegate calls wouldn't really go missing like that.

I didn't understand your second point though.